# Как вернуть значение, не прервав функции?

Tags: lua

Здесь возвращается 0.2 и связано это с тем, что значение возвращается один раз, *не дождавшись итерации таймера*, а потом функция прерывается.

```
function Ani.Speed(maxSpeed, phase)
    if(phase == accelerate) then    
        function speedUp()
            if(maxSpeed ~= 0) then
                maxSpeed = 0
            end
            maxSpeed = maxSpeed + 0.2
            return maxSpeed
        end
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, speedUp, 10)
    end
end
```

Как можно вернуть `maxSpeed`, при этом изменяя его при каждой итерации?

*Ожидаемый результат:*

```
print(maxSpeed) -- 0/0.2/0.4/0.6/(...)/2, где "/" - промежуток в секунду
```

Comment: скорость должна так обнуляться maxSpeed = 0 ? просто логика не понятна.

Comment: @MikeV., логика проста: maxSpeed -- как понимаете, максимальная скорость, которую мы получаем, вызвав функцию `Ani.Speed(speed, accelerate)`. Соответственно, если забиваешь набор скорости -- `accelerate`, то скорость должна **с нуля** набраться до maxSpeed (не стал прописывать логику, по которой определяется количество итераций в зависимости от скорости).

Comment: Еще уточнение: где получается у вас nil,  после  Ani.Speed() или после speedUp() или после timer.performWithDelay() ? или всегда после Ani.Speed()?

Comment: @MikeV., сейчас понимаю, что я накосячил, но не понимаю где. Результаты такие: после SpeedUp и после таймера значение maxSpeed = 0 (не nil). **Внутри**, то есть перед return значение меняется как нужно (от 0 до 2), а если я вне функции делаю следующее присвоение: `local text = AniSpeed(2, accelerate)`, то выходит следующее уведомление: "attempt to concatenate local 'text' (a nil value)"

Comment: Ani.Speed ничего не возвращает же..

Comment: @MikeV., типа надо вставить `return` в корень (в функцию Ani.Speed), а не во вложенные функции?

Comment: ну да . speedUp() вообще можно вынести за пределы  Ani.Speed.

Comment: @MikeV., я обернул в функцию, чтобы было удобно вызывать из другого файла. Все действительно так, но как быть с тем, что она возвращает лишь 0?

Comment: именно поэтому я спрашивал в первом вопросе, почему maxSpeed обнуляется внутри Ani.Speed, в общем-то поэтому и возвращается 0.

Comment: @MikeV., тогда либо обнулять в speedUp, либо за пределами функции?

Comment: возможно нужно просто инициализировать нулем в случае nil ? тогда  так: maxSpeed = (maxSpeed or 0) + 0.2

Comment: @MikeV., это внутри speedUp, a в Ani.Speed поставить return? У меня в этом случае возвращает полученное значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) сделать return и продолжить выполнение нельзя. Насколько я знаю, нельзя это сделать ни в одном языке, где есть return. На то он и return.

2) но, т.к. вы объявляете `Speed` (да, присваивание `nil` всё равно своего рода объявление) в глобальном пространстве, можно не возвращать ничего вообще. Просто вызвать функцию, а потом смотреть на значение Speed. Оно изменится.

В итоге, всё, что вам нужно — просто следить не за возвращаемым функцией значением, а за самой переменной Speed (ну, или описать вопрос получше).

3) Ну и отвечая формально, на изначально заданный вопрос: "вернуть" значение не прервав функции можно только если его не "возвращать" (`return`), а использовать для этого другие методы: например, `print`, или передача другой функции.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно, чтобы при каждом вызове Ani.Speed значение скорости Speed увеличивалось :

```
SPEED_LIMIT = 1.9999  -- где-то в вначале устанавливаете предел скорости
--
Speed= nil   --  текущая скорость , глобальная переменная

function Ani.Speed(phase)
    if(phase == accelerate) then
        function speedUp()
            Speed = Speed or 0 
            if Speed  < SPEED_LIMIT then
               Speed = Speed + 0.2
            end
            print( Speed )
        end
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, speedUp(), 10)
    end
end

Ani.Speed(accelerate)
```

Comment: `print(speed)` выводит в консоль nil.

Comment: У вас же в программе speed устанавливается где-то? я могу в примере поставить в начале = 0 но это ни к чему.... убрал не нужный print()

Comment: Это все так, да вот только мне нужно _возвратить значение_. Ваша функция ничего не возвращает, нет?

Comment: добавил return, хотя, поскольку Speed - глобальная переменная, можно просто использовать ее.

Comment: Speed же не была объявлена. Она является получаемым значением и, кстати, если использовать ваш код, то функция получает, к примеру, 2 и возвращает тоже 2.

Comment: добавил пример использования.

Comment: Запустил пример, вывело в консоль 10 раз "0.2".

Comment: поправил пример

Comment: Здорово, но разве `while(Speed ~= 2) do Speed = Speed  +  0.2 end` не сделает того же? Смысл был каждую секунду прибавлять по 2, а не мгновенно. 
P.S. Код принимает только `Speed = 0`.

Comment: Нужно найти способ вернуть значение, не прерывая функции. Сейчас подредактирую вопрос.

Comment: не передавайте значение Speed в Ani.Speed() , если хотите оставить его глобальное значение, сейчас исправлю пример

Comment: Напечатало только "0.2".

Comment: я тут отлучался, а у вас timer.performWithDelay(1000, speedUp(), 10) 10 раз вызывается?

Comment: 10 раз вызывает speedUp.